# MeCabをpython3で使いたいが 'utf-8' codec can't decode 'utf-8' codec can't decodeというエラーが出てしまう

Tags: python, python3, mecab

[MeCabをMacにインストールする手順](https://qiita.com/nkjm/items/913584c00af199794257)

上記リンク先の手順通りにMeCabをインストールして、pip3 install mecab-python3をpython3で

```py
import MeCab
mecab = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
print(mecab.parse("ダックスフンドが歩いている。"))
```

としたところ`'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position`というエラーが出てしまいました。どなたかご教授お願い致します。

```
[~] mecab -D                                                                                                          13:23:03
filename:   /usr/local/mecab/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic/sys.dic
version:    102
charset:    utf8
type:   0
size:   392126
left size:  1316
right size: 1316

[~] mecab -P                                                                                                          13:24:06
bos-feature: BOS/EOS,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
bos-format:
config-charset: EUC-JP
cost-factor: 700
dicdir: /usr/local/mecab/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic
dump-config: 1
eon-format:
eos-format: EOS\n
eos-format-chasen: EOS\n
eos-format-chasen2: EOS\n
eos-format-simple: EOS\n
eos-format-yomi: \n
eval-size: 8
lattice-level: 0
max-grouping-size: 24
nbest: 1
node-format: %m\t%H\n
node-format-chasen: %m\t%f[7]\t%f[6]\t%F-[0,1,2,3]\t%f[4]\t%f[5]\n
node-format-chasen2: %M\t%f[7]\t%f[6]\t%F-[0,1,2,3]\t%f[4]\t%f[5]\n
node-format-simple: %m\t%F-[0,1,2,3]\n
node-format-yomi: %pS%f[7]
theta: 0.75
unk-eval-size: 4
unk-format: %m\t%H\n
unk-format-chasen: %m\t%m\t%m\t%F-[0,1,2,3]\t\t\n
unk-format-chasen2: %M\t%m\t%m\t%F-[0,1,2,3]\t\t\n
unk-format-yomi: %M

[~] echo ダックスフンドが歩いている。 |mecab -Ochasen                                                                 13:24:13
ダックスフンド ダックスフンド ダックスフンド 名詞-一般
が   ガ   が   助詞-格助詞-一般
歩い  アルイ 歩く  動詞-自立   五段・カ行イ音便    連用タ接続
て   テ   て   助詞-接続助詞
いる  イル  いる  動詞-非自立  一段  基本形
。   。   。   記号-句点
EOS
```

```py
import sys 
sys.getdefaultencoding() 
'utf-8'
```

となっていました。

Comment: `config-charset: EUC-JP` は少し気になりますが、辞書自体はUTF-8で構築されているようですし、実際に `mecab` コマンドはUTF-8環境で文字化けせず動作しており、よく解らないですね。
一応、Python側で辞書の `charset` を確認する方法を回答に追記しました。

Answer (score 3):

#### 文字コードの不一致

Python3のソースコードのデフォルトエンコーディングはUTF-8で、[文字列(`str`)はUnicodeを保持します](https://docs.python.jp/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support)。
MeCabの辞書の（おそらく質問者さんが使っているであろう）`ipadic` はデフォルトでは[EUCで作られます](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#charset)。
<del>この不一致がエラーの原因です。</del>（追記: 違っていました。質問者さんの辞書はUTF-8とのこと）
`./configure --with-charset=utf8` でUTF-8の辞書を構築するのが、最も簡単な解決方法だと思います。

#### 辞書の文字コードの確認

`mecab` コマンド はオプション `-D, --dictionary-info` で辞書の情報を出力します。

```
$ mecab -D
```

文字コードがUTF-8であれば `charset:   UTF-8` のように出力されます。
Python側でも以下のように確認できるようです。

```
mecab = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
info = mecab.dictionary_info()
print(info.charset)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
[~] mecab -D                                                                                                                                  
filename: /usr/local/mecab/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic/sys.dic
version: 102
charset: utf8
type: 0
size: 392126
left size: 1316
right size: 1316

import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'

となりました他に考えられる原因はありますでしょうか？

Comment: @RyosukeYokota なるほど。リンク先をよく読んだら UTF-8 で作成する手順になっていましたね。
コメントの投稿は私にしか通知されせんから、上記 `mecab -D` の出力は質問に追記してみてください。
また、その際は省略なしのエラーメッセージや、念のため `mecab -P` の出力、`echo ダックスフンドが歩いている。 |mecab -Ochasen` が成功するのか、あたりも含めるとよいと思います。

Comment: 詳しく回答していただきありがとうございます。情報を追加しますので、もう一度見てもらえると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://qiita.com/musaprg/items/9a572ad5c4e28f79d2ae
の記事を参考にして解決しました。ありがとうございました。またなにかあればよろしくお願い致します。