# pythonでMeCab、neologdで形態素解析すると結果が文字化け（ユニコードエスケープ）する

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, mecab, 文字化け

初めまして。表題の通り、PythonにてMeCab、NEogold辞書で形態素解析をしたいのですが、結果が上手く出せません。
環境：Windows10 64bit、Anaconda3、jupyter notebook
※辞書はコード中のフォルダにインストールしてあります。

以下のコードは実行すると正しく結果が出力されているように見えます。

```
import MeCab
# ipadic
tagger = MeCab.Tagger('-d C:\ProgramData\Mecab\dic\ipadic')
result = tagger.parse("すもももももももものうち")
print(result)
```

↓出力結果

```
すもも 名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,すもも,スモモ,スモモ
も   助詞,係助詞,*,*,*,*,も,モ,モ
もも  名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,もも,モモ,モモ
も   助詞,係助詞,*,*,*,*,も,モ,モ
もも  名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,もも,モモ,モモ
の   助詞,連体化,*,*,*,*,の,ノ,ノ
うち  名詞,非自立,副詞可能,*,*,*,うち,ウチ,ウチ
EOS
```

```
# neologd
tagger = MeCab.Tagger('-d C:\ProgramData\Mecab\dic\ipadic-neologd')
result = tagger.parse("すもももももももものうち")
print(result)
```

↓出力結果

```
すもももももももものうち    名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,すもももももももものうち,スモモモモモモモモノウチ,スモモモモモモモモノウチ
EOS
```

しかし、以下を実行するとしばらくしてから（なぜか時間がかかる）エラーになります。

```
# neologd
tagger = MeCab.Tagger('-d C:\ProgramData\Mecab\dic\ipadic-neologd')
result = tagger.parse("JO")
print(result)
```

エラー発生

```
Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(928, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(928, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 143, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 456, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 486, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 438, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 120, in _handle_event
    event_f()
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 382, in _flush
    parent=self.parent_header, ident=self.topic)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 737, in send
    to_send = self.serialize(msg, ident)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 625, in serialize
    content = self.pack(content)
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\session.py", line 103, in <lambda>
    ensure_ascii=False, allow_nan=False,
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\jsonapi.py", line 43, in dumps
    s = s.encode('utf8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 310-311: surrogates not allowed
```

また、以下のように書き換えると、結果がエスケープ文字列で表示されます。

```
node = tagger.parseToNode("JO")
word = node.surface # 分解された単語部分
wclass = node.feature.split(',') # 単語の説明部分（カンマで区切ってリスト化）
# 先頭を飛ばして次へ
node = node.next
word = node.surface # 分解された単語部分
wclass = node.feature.split(',') # 単語の説明部分（カンマで区切ってリスト化）
print(word)
print(wclass)
```

↓出力結果

```
JO
['̾\udcbb\udcec', '\udcb8\udcc7ͭ̾\udcbb\udcec', '\udcc1ȿ\udca5', '*', '*', '*', '*']
```

このような環境で、Twitterのタイムラインを形態素解析しているですが、このようなエスケープ文字列の単語として識別される単語がいくつも出てきてしまい、正しいのかよくわからない状況です。

これは、辞書のインストール・作成の仕方に問題があるのでしょうか？
あるいは、文字列のエンコードの問題、その他の問題などでしょうか？
分かる方いましたら、ご教授いただきたいです。

ちなみに、コマンドプロンプトでPythonを起動して実行すると以下のような結果になります。

```
>>> tagger = MeCab.Tagger('-d C:\ProgramData\Mecab\dic\ipadic-neologd')
>>> result = tagger.parse("JO")
>>> print(result)
JO      ̾��,��ͭ̾��,�ȿ�,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

追記

```
import MeCab
tagger = MeCab.Tagger('-d C:\ProgramData\Mecab\dic\ipadic-neologd')
info = tagger.dictionary_info()
print('neologd')
print(info.charset)
print(info.version)
print('ipadic')
tagger = MeCab.Tagger('-d C:\ProgramData\Mecab\dic\ipadic')
info = tagger.dictionary_info()
print(info.charset)
print(info.version)
```

↓出力結果
neologd
-utf-8
102
ipadic
UTF-8
102

使ったコミット
https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/commit/45315fdad28456d3e98d5b36bea46a8010235cac

Comment: 色んな状況があるようです。どれか参考になれば。[PythonでMeCabを使うと出力が文字化けしてしまいます。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/57405/26370), [MeCabをpython3で使いたいが 'utf-8' codec can't decode 'utf-8' codec can't decodeというエラーが出てしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42804/26370), [Windowsで、MeCabとCaboChaのエンコードが分からない](https://teratail.com/questions/228302), [MeCabの文字化け](https://teratail.com/questions/85778), [Windows10(64bit)でMecabの環境構築に苦戦した](https://qiita.com/Asuka_y/items/ea945866a38c7ac58f6d)

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回のケースとはちょっと違っていましたが、参考にさせていただきます。